# How can I create a lower diagonal matrix in Sympy?

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

How can I create a lower diagonal square matrix of size `p` in **Sympy**?

For example, if `p == 4` I want to obtain the following matrix:

```
| 0 0 0 0 |
| 1 0 0 0 |
| 0 1 0 0 |
| 0 0 1 0 |
```

I am currently using this approach, but I was wondering if there was a function similar to `eye(p)` that would work.

```
def f(i, j):
    if i - j == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


print(Matrix(p, p, f))
```

Here's the output if `p == 4`:

```
Matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just borrow Numpy's [`np.eye()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.eye.html#numpy-eye) and use the `k` parameter, which just "shift" the diagonal (and seems to be unsupported by SymPy's `eye()`):

```
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np



print(sym.Matrix(np.eye(4, k=-1, dtype=int)))
# Matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

or:

```
print(sym.Matrix(np.eye(4, 4, -1, dtype=int)))
# Matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```